# How to fetch Azure AD information in big query GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

We wish to connect to Azure AD to get AD group information and build a pipeline to flow this information in GCP Big Query
eg:
AD Group Name -- Userid -- user email id
AD_GROUP_INDIA    101       abc@company.com

Is there any direct connector / python library available for the same?

Regards,
Kiran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be the [MS Graph SDK for Python](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python-core), currently in preview. Also, you can do REST calls directly to the [MS Graph API.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api)

You need to:

1. Choose what [authentication schema or flow to use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-flows-app-scenarios)
2. [Register an Azure AD application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/walkthrough-register-app-azure-active-directory)
3. [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/migrate-azure-ad-graph-configure-permissions?tabs=powershell) and [consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/application-consent-experience#app-requires-a-permission-outside-of-the-users-scope-of-authority) `Group.Read.All` permission.
4. Authenticate and obtain an access token for scope [https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`](https://graph.microsoft.com/.default%60)  (Will include all permissions exposed for MS Graph) using [Azure Identity client library for Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-python) or [MSAL Python](https://msal-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)
5. Call one of the MS Graph group operations: `client.get('/groups')` or `client.get('/groups/{id}')`

For more information about the MS Graph group supported operations/endpoints take a look at [Working with groups in Microsoft Graph.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/groups-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0)